# Spark stuck in UNDEFINED status when submit a job in AWS EMR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am running a spark submit using the following script by using an AWS EMR (version emr-5.26.0) on m4.xlarge instances :

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Define variables to get script parameters
MAIN_SPARK_URI=$1 # looks like s3://bucket/app/src/main.py
MODELS_BASE_URI=$2 # looks like s3://bucket/app/models/models.pkl
APP_EGG_URI=$3 # looks like s3://bucket/app/src/app.egg
CONFIG_FILE_URI=$4 # looks like s3://bucket/app/src/config.ini
INPUT_DATA_URI=$5 # looks like s3://data-bucket/app/raw/consumption
VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT=$6 # looks like s3://bucket/app/virtualenv

# Launch a spark submit
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name water_consumption_job \
--conf spark.driver.cores=1 \
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=6G \
--conf spark.driver.memory=6G \
--conf spark.spark.executor.instances=4 \
--conf spark.executor.cores=4 \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=3G \
--conf spark.executor.memory=3G \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=false \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
--conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false \
--conf spark.sql.caseSensitive=true \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=. \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION=${CONFIG_FILE_URI} \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 \
--conf spark.executorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=. \
--conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path=./venv/bin/python \
--conf spark.pyspark.python=./venv/bin/python \
--conf spark.pyspark.driver.python=./venv/bin/python \
--archives $VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT/venv.tar.gz#venv \
--files ${CONFIG_FILE_URI} \
--py-files ${APP_EGG_URI} \
${MAIN_SPARK_URI} \
--pipeline water_consumptions \
--input $INPUT_DATA_URI \
--models $MODELS_BASE_URI/models.pkl
--collection mongo://consumptions/waterConsumptions \
```

But it seems that the job does not run even it finally appears to be completed. I got the following logs :

```
22/10/25 17:43:46 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: [Tue Oct 25 17:43:46 +0000 2022] Application is Activated, waiting for resources to be assigned for AM.  Details : AM Partition = CORE ; Partition Resource = <memory:24576, vCores:16> ; Queue's Absolute capacity = 100.0 % ; Queue's Absolute used capacity = 0.0 % ; Queue's Absolute max capacity = 100.0 % ; 
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1666719826565
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://<something>/proxy/application_1666719665916_0001/
     user: hadoop
22/10/25 17:43:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/10/25 17:43:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-d83396ad-7b53-4e8b-a2e8-e9f8374f36a2
22/10/25 17:43:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-6a969106-81af-465a-a1eb-2eabd628f4b1
Command exiting with ret '0'
```

The job stucks in a status `UNDEFINED` and ends successfully. Things are running but the python script (`MAIN_SPARK_URI`) is definitely not executed. I am expected to see some logs with some `ACCEPTED / FINISHED`.

I am trying to understand what happens but that's difficult. In my opinion, something is going wrong in the spark-submit.
Please don't hesitate to ask for more details. Any help would be really appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

When facing such an issue try to configure memory better to fit with the kind of instance you're running your code on.

In my opinion, I over-configured the memory to allocate and the job was not able to start. Here is a configuration that makes the job running :

```bash
--conf spark.driver.cores=1 \
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=1024m \
--conf spark.driver.memory=4000m \
--conf spark.spark.executor.instances=3 \
--conf spark.executor.cores=3 \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=512m \
--conf spark.executor.memory=1024m \
```